# Limpar Parametros URL após include

Tags: php, url, include

Quando passo parâmetros na URL para um determinado arquivo através de um GET, e este arquivo realiza as alterações necessárias, o mesmo tem um `include` para retornar a página inicial da ação realizada.

Quando retorna para a página, as informações passadas como parâmetros ainda ficam na URL (exemplo: `site.com/página.php?id=31`). Como faço para ao retornar ele atualizar e ficar apenas a página real (`site.com/pagina.php`)?

Arquivo com include ( vai para o cabeçalho, faz as alterações e retorna para onde estava na pasta templates/inicio.php):

```
<?php
$excluir=1;
include("includes/cabecalho.php");

if(isset($excluiu)){

    if($excluiu==1 || $excluiu==0){
        include("templates/inicio.php");
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('O Sistema apresentou algum erro, fale com o administrador!');</script>";
    }

}else{
    echo "<script>alert('O sistema apresentou algum erro, fale com o administrador!');</script>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Como é que você está fazendo o include? Seria legal explicar melhor a questão, pois você diz que tem um `include` para retornar à pagina inicial, o que não faz muito sentido. O que você chama de "retornar"?

Comment: Rodrigo, um pouco de código com as partes relevantes pode deixar a pergunta mais clara

Answer (score -1):

Para um redirecionamento é melhor você trocar.

```
include("templates/inicio.php")
```

por

```
header('Location: templates/inicio.php'); ou 
header('Location: http://site.com/pagina.php'); //Ai já redireciona.
```

mais se não for caso de "Redirecionamento" como descrito na pergunta não resolvera o problema.

Comment: Oi, Luiz, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Pode explicar porquê sua solução resolve o problema? O guia [answer] tem mais dicas e pode [edit] a resposta sempre que quiser.

Comment: A solução do Luiz faz com que outros erros ocorram. Não funciona. Porém, acho que não precisarei mais. Qualquer coisa informo aqui novamente.

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto caso tenha encontrado a solução do problema, poste ela como uma resposta.

Comment: Não encontrei. Vou querer deixar mesmo a URL e fazer de outra forma. Mesmo assim, Obrigado.